# How to launch fragment with app Widget click?

Tags: java, android, widget, fragment

How can I open the fragment in app widget? here is my AppWidgetProvider class code when i tried one more time again it is working for activities but not working for fragments is there any way to open fragment with widget clicked:

```
public class ApprovalWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

private Gson gson;
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    gson = new Gson();
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.approval_widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.example_widget_button, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.approval_widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.example_widget_button2, pendingIntent2);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }
}
```